# Fragment become null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am developing Android application and i have in my Main activity a fragment with this:

```
        searchInnerPlaylistFragment = InnerPlaylistFragment.newInstance();

        Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
        bdl.putString(InnerPlaylistFragment.PLAYLIST_ID_KEY, ytf.getId());
        bdl.putString(InnerPlaylistFragment.PLAYLIST_TITLE_KEY, ytf.getTitle());
        bdl.putInt(InnerPlaylistFragment.PLAYLIST_VIDEO_NUMBER_KEY, videoNum);
        searchInnerPlaylistFragment.setArguments(bdl);

        ft.replace(R.id.search_inner_list_fragment, searchInnerPlaylistFragment).commit();
```

And when i open the "Don't keep activities" option in the developer Options, and go to background with my app and return to the app the `searchInnerPlaylistFragment` become null but it's still in the activity.

There is an option to save this fragment?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly save instance state of Fragment, you should do following codes:

In the fragment, save instance state by override onSaveInstanceState and restore on onActivityCreated:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's state here
    }
}
...
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

//Save the fragment's state here


}
```

And important point, in the activity, you have to save fragment's instance on onSaveInstanceState and restore on onCreate.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's instance
        mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
                    savedInstanceState, "mContent");
        ...
    }
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

//Save the fragment's instance
getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);


}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your fragment on backStack, so that when you press back or navigate to back screen you can get it back from stack

change your fragment replacing line as

ft.replace(R.id.search_inner_list_fragment, searchInnerPlaylistFragment).addToBackStack().commit();

and when you want to get this fragment back you can pop it like
    manager.popBackStack();